# Is there any way to aggregate table's data in cassandra 2.1.6?

Tags: cassandra, aggregation

I am new in Cassandra.  I want to aggregate my columns like `SUM()`, `MAX()`, etc.

So is there any way like functions or query or something that can help me ?

Comment: nope. You will have to write your own logic.

Comment: Thanks Arun,Is there any API for java that perform aggregation and roll up my data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CQL (Cassandra Query Language) built into Cassandra 2.1.6 only supports the count() aggregation function.

So to do aggregation in Cassandra, there are a few options:

1. Do a query that returns all the rows you want to aggregate, and sum them on the client side in java/python/etc.
2. Write your application to do aggregation of your data when inserting it into Cassandra, and update the aggregated data as you insert additional data.
3. Pair Cassandra with a component like Apache spark using the Cassandra Spark Connector.  This requires some effort to learn and set up, but offers aggregation functions and many additional analytics features.
4. Upgrade to Cassandra 2.2.0 (currently available as release candidate 1).  A new feature in 2.2 is support for user defined functions.  With UDF you can define aggregation functions.  See an example [here](http://christopher-batey.blogspot.com/2015/05/cassandra-aggregates-min-max-avg-group.html).

Comment: As per your answer i go through with Apache Spark,
Spark completed all my needs but there is one problem with that.

Before Spark when i request for fetch big Cassandra table (more than 1 lac records) using Java API it works fine, but now using spark it take 5-6 minutes for fetch data.

In spark i seen many task and Executor in log. might be this is the reason that Spark divided process in many task!

Comment: You might want to start a new question for the slow fetch time since there could be many reasons for that.  When pairing Spark with Cassandra you want to take advantage of data locality, so your spark workers should be run on the Cassandra nodes, and your application should keep the partition keys in mind.

Comment: 2016 update to answer: Cassandra 2.2 is out, and has min, max, avg, sum, and count built in. [docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useQueryStdAggregate.html) You do get the performance hit of reading every row to do this, so depending on your application you may want to also maintain aggregate tables for whatever granularity(s) you want.